# How to install JayDeBeApi in python 3.6

Tags: python

I'm running python 3.6 in my windows 10. I need to install JayDeBeApi.I tried to install in with pip install statement first & got the following error message[image]

Then I tried to install it using conda install & got this message
[image]

Can you please suggest me how to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that I think will work on your computer (it works on mine)

- Go to [this github repo](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi)
- Click 'Clone or download' and then 'Download ZIP'
- Extract the ZIP
- In your terminal:

  ```
  cd YourDownloadPath/ExtractedFolder/jaydebeapi-master
  python setup.py install
  ```

It should install properly.

**NOTE: I use python 3.4.3 and Windows Vista so it *may* not work.**