# How to install jaydebeapi in python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7 on Window7. I need to install jaydebeapi. I tried

```
conda install JayDeBeApi
```

But I got following error
[installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiKNX.png)

Also I tried the steps mentioned in

> [How to install JayDeBeApi in python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870831/how-to-install-jaydebeapi-in-python-3-6)

but `import jaydebeapi` is giving error message

```
ImportError: No module named jaydebeapi
```

in my anaconda with spyder 3.2.6

I also downloaded it from

> https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi 
>   and used following command in Anaconda promt

```
python setup.py install
```

It works in anaconda prompt. Please refer the screen shot
[Running in conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbMvC.png)
But import statement is still giving error in python 
Can you please suggest how to import jaydebeapi

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: can you read my answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run pip install ModuleName on your CMD

```
pip install JayDeBeApi
```

Resultat :

```
Collecting JayDeBeApi
 Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/e2/a84253efa32c104256d
44731513b8d8b7e47a890b6e44fb42c54688a5dc2/JayDeBeApi-1.1.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting JPype1 (from JayDeBeApi)
  Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/4b/60a3e63d51714d4d7ef
1b1efdf84315d118a0a80a5b085bb52a7e2428cdc/JPype1-0.6.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: JPype1, JayDeBeApi
 Running setup.py install for JPype1 ... done
  Successfully installed JPype1-0.6.3 JayDeBeApi-1.1.1
```

Done:

```
>>> import jaydebeapi
>>>
```